# What to write in docker-compose.yml for self mantained docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have next progress

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 443:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/fullchain.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/privkey.key
    volumes:
      - /path/data:/var/lib/registry
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.my-site.com:/certs
```

Works fine, but how should i pass htpasswd ?

Comment: You should probably use a secrets management tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First need to create `htpasswd` file with `-B`

```
sudo htpasswd -cbB .htpasswd <login> <password>
```

then add to `docker-compose.yml`

```
environment:
  REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
  REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/.htpasswd
  REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
volumes:
  - <path to folder with .htpasswd>:/auth
```